# Downloading many files from EarthData(GES Disc) with wget. Getting ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable for some of the files

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

I am trying to download this dataset [GPM Precipitation](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/jobs/results/5ede127d3c48d45cb0daff94) for a project. For my defined data range I need around 217 files from the dataset. There are [instructions](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-access#windows_wget) how to download the data in bulk with wget , which I followed, but some of the files are not getting downloaded because of "503 error Service Temporarily Unavailable". As you can see in the images below only 88 files are downloaded. I tried the same procedure with a different dataset [GLDAS](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/GLDAS_NOAH025_M_2.1/summary?keywords=GLDAS) and I did not encounter the same problem. Every file was downloaded.

Why is this happening for the GPM Precipitation dataset?

Some of the output in CMD:

```
(base) C:\Users\sport>D:

(base) D:\>wget --load-cookies D:\.urs_cookies --save-cookies D:\.urs_cookies --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies --user=delloman --ask-password --content-disposition -i subset_GPM_3IMERGM_06_20200608_102849.txt
Password for user 'delloman':
--2020-06-08 12:30:29--  https://docserver.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/public/project/GPM/IMERG_ATBD_V06.pdf
Resolving docserver.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (docserver.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)... 198.118.197.32
Connecting to docserver.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (docserver.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.32|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2486295 (2,4M) [application/pdf]
Saving to: 'IMERG_ATBD_V06.pdf'

IMERG_ATBD_V06.pdf            100%[=================================================>]   2,37M   746KB/s    in 3,3s

2020-06-08 12:30:33 (746 KB/s) - 'IMERG_ATBD_V06.pdf' saved [2486295/2486295]

--2020-06-08 12:30:33--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/doc/README.GPM.pdf
Resolving gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)... 198.118.197.50
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1036469 (1012K) [application/pdf]
Saving to: 'README.GPM.pdf'

README.GPM.pdf                100%[=================================================>]   1012K   444KB/s    in 2,3s

2020-06-08 12:30:36 (444 KB/s) - 'README.GPM.pdf' saved [1036469/1036469]

--2020-06-08 12:30:36--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize/?scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=e2WVk8Pw6weeLUKZYOxvTQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov%2Fdata-redirect&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8zSU1FUkdNLjA2LzIwMDIvM0ItTU8uTVMuTVJHLjNJTUVSRy4yMDAyMDQwMS1TMDAwMDAwLUUyMzU5NTkuMDQuVjA2Qi5IREY1Lm5jND9wcmVjaXBpdGF0aW9uWzA6MF1bMTg0OToxOTU5XVsxMzY5OjE0NTldLHRpbWUsbG9uWzE4NDk6MTk1OV0sbGF0WzEzNjk6MTQ1OV0 [following]
--2020-06-08 12:30:38--  https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize/?scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=e2WVk8Pw6weeLUKZYOxvTQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov%2Fdata-redirect&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8zSU1FUkdNLjA2LzIwMDIvM0ItTU8uTVMuTVJHLjNJTUVSRy4yMDAyMDQwMS1TMDAwMDAwLUUyMzU5NTkuMDQuVjA2Qi5IREY1Lm5jND9wcmVjaXBpdGF0aW9uWzA6MF1bMTg0OToxOTU5XVsxMzY5OjE0NTldLHRpbWUsbG9uWzE4NDk6MTk1OV0sbGF0WzEzNjk6MTQ1OV0
Resolving urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)... 198.118.243.33
Connecting to urs.earthdata.nasa.gov (urs.earthdata.nasa.gov)|198.118.243.33|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
The name is too long, 443 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is index.html@scope=uid&app_type=401&client_id=e2WVk8Pw6weeLUKZYOxvTQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov%2Fdata-redirect&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8.
Location: https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data-redirect?code=557ff4789336dc03b3125448c2f9202979c826f365121a32a1f48c05bf4b493a&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8zSU1FUkdNLjA2LzIwMDIvM0ItTU8uTVMuTVJHLjNJTUVSRy4yMDAyMDQwMS1TMDAwMDAwLUUyMzU5NTkuMDQuVjA2Qi5IREY1Lm5jND9wcmVjaXBpdGF0aW9uWzA6MF1bMTg0OToxOTU5XVsxMzY5OjE0NTldLHRpbWUsbG9uWzE4NDk6MTk1OV0sbGF0WzEzNjk6MTQ1OV0 [following]
--2020-06-08 12:30:39--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data-redirect?code=557ff4789336dc03b3125448c2f9202979c826f365121a32a1f48c05bf4b493a&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8zSU1FUkdNLjA2LzIwMDIvM0ItTU8uTVMuTVJHLjNJTUVSRy4yMDAyMDQwMS1TMDAwMDAwLUUyMzU5NTkuMDQuVjA2Qi5IREY1Lm5jND9wcmVjaXBpdGF0aW9uWzA6MF1bMTg0OToxOTU5XVsxMzY5OjE0NTldLHRpbWUsbG9uWzE4NDk6MTk1OV0sbGF0WzEzNjk6MTQ1OV0
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
The name is too long, 369 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is data-redirect@code=557ff4789336dc03b3125448c2f9202979c826f365121a32a1f48c05bf4b493a&state=aHR0cHM6Ly9ncG0xLmdlc2Rpc2MuZW9zZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L29wZW5kYXAvR1BNX0wzL0dQTV8zSU1FUkdNLjA2LzIwMDIvM0ItTU8uTVMuTVJHLjNJTUVSRy4yMDAyMDQwMS1TMDAwMDAwLUUyM.
Location: https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459] [following]
--2020-06-08 12:30:40--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-     [ <=>                                              ]  60,73K  --.-KB/s    in 0,01s

2020-06-08 12:34:53 (4,66 MB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62190]

--2020-06-08 12:34:53--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020501-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,38K   211KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:35:14 (211 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62850]

--2020-06-08 12:35:14--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020601-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,57K   261KB/s    in 0,2s

2020-06-08 12:35:15 (261 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [63043]

--2020-06-08 12:35:15--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020701-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,26K   246KB/s    in 0,2s

2020-06-08 12:35:21 (246 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62726]

--2020-06-08 12:35:21--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020801-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,35K   244KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:35:24 (244 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62827]

--2020-06-08 12:35:24--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020901-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,27K   227KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:35:45 (227 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20020901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62740]

--2020-06-08 12:35:45--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021001-     [  <=>                                             ]  60,63K   227KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:35:53 (227 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62087]

--2020-06-08 12:35:53--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021101-S000000-E235959.11.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:36:58 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:36:58--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2002/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021201-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,30K   222KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:12 (222 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20021201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62771]

--2020-06-08 12:37:12--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030101-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,05K   222KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:14 (222 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62516]

--2020-06-08 12:37:14--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030201-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,25K   213KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:45 (213 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62719]

--2020-06-08 12:37:45--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030301-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,09K   221KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:46 (221 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62556]

--2020-06-08 12:37:46--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030401-     [  <=>                                             ]  60,44K   208KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:48 (208 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [61888]

--2020-06-08 12:37:48--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030501-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,31K   223KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:50 (223 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62782]

--2020-06-08 12:37:50--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030601-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,01K   220KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:37:53 (220 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62475]

--2020-06-08 12:37:53--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:38:23 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:38:23--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:39:33 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:39:33--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030901-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,24K   212KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:39:35 (212 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20030901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62711]

--2020-06-08 12:39:35--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031001-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,41K   219KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:39:37 (219 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62880]

--2020-06-08 12:39:37--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031101-S000000-E235959.11.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:39:58 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:39:58--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2003/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031201-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,26K   214KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:40:19 (214 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20031201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62732]

--2020-06-08 12:40:19--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040101-     [  <=>                                             ]  60,67K   217KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:40:27 (217 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040101-S000000-E235959.01.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62121]

--2020-06-08 12:40:27--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040201-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,39K   218KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:40:54 (218 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040201-S000000-E235959.02.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62862]

--2020-06-08 12:40:54--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040301-     [  <=>                                             ]  60,50K   213KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:40:56 (213 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040301-S000000-E235959.03.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [61952]

--2020-06-08 12:40:56--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040401-     [  <=>                                             ]  60,52K   224KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:41:00 (224 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040401-S000000-E235959.04.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [61977]

--2020-06-08 12:41:00--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040501-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,60K   223KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:41:03 (223 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040501-S000000-E235959.05.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [63076]

--2020-06-08 12:41:03--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040601-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,48K   214KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:41:06 (214 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040601-S000000-E235959.06.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62959]

--2020-06-08 12:41:06--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040701-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,00K   218KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:41:11 (218 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040701-S000000-E235959.07.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62466]

--2020-06-08 12:41:11--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040801-S000000-E235959.08.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:41:58 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:41:58--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040901-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,52K   130KB/s    in 0,5s

2020-06-08 12:42:40 (130 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20040901-S000000-E235959.09.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [62993]

--2020-06-08 12:42:40--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041001-     [  <=>                                             ]  61,55K   214KB/s    in 0,3s

2020-06-08 12:42:42 (214 KB/s) - '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041001-S000000-E235959.10.V06B.HDF5.nc4' saved [63027]

--2020-06-08 12:42:42--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041101-S000000-E235959.11.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
2020-06-08 12:42:53 ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable.

--2020-06-08 12:42:53--  https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGM.06/2004/3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4?precipitation[0:0][1849:1959][1369:1459],time,lon[1849:1959],lat[1369:1459]
Connecting to gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.50|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-netcdf]
Saving to: '3B-MO.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20041201-S000000-E235959.12.V06B.HDF5.nc4'

FINISHED --2020-06-08 13:00:59--
Total wall clock time: 30m 34s
Downloaded: 88 files, 8,5M in 29s (298 KB/s)

(base) D:\>
```

Comment: I do not readily see anything incorrect about your code or usage. There is a `Feedback` button on the https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/#top page. That might provide a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the support of the website. The GES DISC was experiencing unusually high traffic yesterday. There was no problem with my command. Today every file was dowloaded as expected.